# Unable to cast 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet`1 to System.Collections.Generic.IList`1

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, tdd, fluent-nhibernate-test

I have a domain class:

```
public class Agencia : IEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual string Identificacao { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Pessoa> Gerentes { get; protected set; }

    public Agencia()
    {
        Gerentes = new List<Pessoa>();
    }

    public virtual void AddGerente(Pessoa gerente)
    {
        Gerentes.Add(gerente);
    }
    public virtual void AddGerentes(params Pessoa[] gerentes)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(gerentes, (pessoa) => Gerentes.Add(pessoa));
    }
}

public class Pessoa: IEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }

}
```

With this convention (defined as set `AsSet`)

```
public class AgenciaConvention : IAutoMappingOverride<Agencia>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Agencia> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasManyToMany(a => a.Gerentes).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().AsSet().Not.Inverse();
    }
}
```

When I run this test:

```
[TestMethod]
[Description("Uma agência tem vários gerêntes")]
public void AgenciaTemVariosGerentes()
{
    // Arrange
    var fix = new Fixture();
    var currentUser = GetLoggedUser();

    // Create a List<Pessoa>

    var gerentes = fix.Build<Pessoa>()
                        .With(p => p.Nome)
                        .With(p => p.CPF)
                        .With(p => p.CreateBy, currentUser)
                        .OmitAutoProperties()
                        .CreateMany<Pessoa>(10).ToList();

    // Action

    new PersistenceSpecification<Agencia>(Session)
            .CheckProperty(p => p.Nome, fix.Create<string>().Truncate(80))
            .CheckProperty(p => p.Identificacao, fix.Create<string>().Truncate(10))
            .CheckReference(p => p.Regional,
                fix.Build<Regional>()
                    .With(p => p.Nome)
                    .OmitAutoProperties()
                    .Create()
            , new IDEqualityComparer())
            .CheckList(p => p.Gerentes, gerentes, new IDEqualityComparer())
            .CheckReference(p => p.CreateBy, currentUser, new IDEqualityComparer())
            .VerifyTheMappings(); // Assert
}
```

How can I test this list?

> The collection should be `AsSet`, it necessary that the Parent and Children fields are PK, FK

**Full Error:**

Test Name:  AgenciaTemVariosGerentes
Test FullName:  {OMMITED}.Integration.Test.AgenciaTest.AgenciaTemVariosGerentes
Test Source:    {OMMITED}.Integration.Test\AgenciaTest.cs : line 22
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:02,4093555

Result Message: 
Test method {OMMITED}.Integration.Test.AgenciaTest.AgenciaTemVariosGerentes threw exception: 
NHibernate.PropertyAccessException: Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.Regional ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet`1[CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.Pessoa]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.Pessoa]'.
Result StackTrace:
at (Object , Object[] , SetterCallback )
   at NHibernate.Bytecode.Lightweight.AccessOptimizer.SetPropertyValues(Object target, Object[] values)
   at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer.SetPropertyValuesWithOptimizer(Object entity, Object[] values)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer.SetPropertyValuesWithOptimizer(Object entity, Object[] values)
   at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer.SetPropertyValues(Object entity, Object[] values)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.SetPropertyValues(Object obj, Object[] values, EntityMode entityMode)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSave(Object entity, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
   at FluentNHibernate.Testing.PersistenceSpecification`1.TransactionalSave(Object propertyValue)
   at FluentNHibernate.Testing.Values.ReferenceProperty`2.HasRegistered(PersistenceSpecification`1 specification)
   at FluentNHibernate.Testing.PersistenceSpecification`1.RegisterCheckedProperty(Property`1 property, IEqualityComparer equalityComparer)
   at FluentNHibernate.Testing.PersistenceSpecificationExtensions.CheckReference[T](PersistenceSpecification`1 spec, Expression`1 expression, Object propertyValue, IEqualityComparer propertyComparer)
   at CreditoImobiliarioBB.Repository.Integration.Test.AgenciaTest.AgenciaTemVariosGerentes() in {OMMITED}.Integration.Test\AgenciaTest.cs:line 27

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sets don't implement `IList<T>`.

Define your properties as `ICollection<T>` instead.